# Como podría desde un número de la lista sumar-le los dos próximos números a partir de el

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuplas

Tengo una pregunta y no sé muy bien como formularla, también quería destacar que en el título de la pregunta no sé que bien se puede entender, pero en todo caso aquí intentaré explicarme lo mejor que pueda.

Vamos a decir que tenemos una función con una tupla adentro:

```
def suma():
     tabla_numer = (1,2,5,6,3,7,8,5)
```

Ahora mi pregunta seria:

**¿Cómo podría desde un número de la lista sumar-le los dos próximos que vienen a partir de el?**.

Por ejemplo, que al fijarme en el número 5 el programa le sume los dos que vienen delante suyo.

En este caso si nos paramos en el 5 y des de ahí queremos sumar los dos que vienen serian el 6 y el 3, el programa debería devolver 5+6+3 = 14.

He intentado pensar como podría hacer que al llegar por ejemplo al 5 haga la suma que estoy buscando, lo que hice fue sustituir un carácter($) en el lugar del 5, para así al llegar al carácter sepa que es donde tiene que hacer la suma. Os dejo aquí un ejemplo de lo que quiero decir con eso:

```
def suma():
     num = 5
     list_suma = []
     referen = '$'
     tabla_numer = ('1','2','$','6','3','7','8','5')
     while range(len(tabla_numer)):
         for i in tabla_numer:
             if i == reference:
                 "lo que estoy preguntando xd"             
             else:
                  if i != referen:
                       list_suma.append(i)
         return sum(lista_suma)
```

Es un ejemplo básico y no dudo que esté bien, solo es para que os hagáis una idea.

Gracias de Antemano!!

Comment: ¿Qué pasa con los casos límite? Me refiero a los casos en que el valor no tiene otros 2 que le sigan, es decir, le sigue 1 valor (es el penúltimo) o no le sigue ningún valor (es el último).

Comment: En eso no pensé, pero mi propósito era solo utilizarlo en la parte de al medio de la tupla, donde si puede haber 2 que le sigan

Comment: Mi intención es no hacer un loop que se repite cada vez, sino que al llegar al 5 por ejemplo te hace la suma de los 3 números (5+6+3), y luego sigue con la tupla

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hay multiples formas de resolver tu problema, yo te voy a dejar dos, siguiendo con tu ejemplo:

```
tupla = (1,2,5,6,3,7,8,5)

def suma(tupla, numero_buscar):
    try:
        idx = tupla.index(numero_buscar)
    except ValueError:
        raise ValueError("El número a buscar no se encuentra en la tupla")

    try:
        return tupla[idx] + tupla[idx+1] + tupla[idx+2]
    except IndexError:
        raise IndexError("has alcanzado el limite de la tupla, por favor introduce otro número")


print(suma(5))
```

**Salida:** `14`

#### Explicación

1. He sacado la tupla de la función y la he puesto como parámetro, esto no es necesario hacerlo, pero si es una buena práctica de programación
2. Con el método `.index()` que tienen las tuplas, este método **busca un número en la tupla** y devuelve su indice
3. Por último en el `return` accedo a ese indice y a los dos siguientes para sumarlos

Resaltar que he usado `try ... except` para capturar posibles errores, como que el número buscado no se encuentre en la lista, o que se encuentre en las últimas posiciones, como señalo Mauricio en los comentarios.

En el caso de que quieras utilizar más indices, se podría hacer tedioso <s>por lo que puedes usar [List Comprehension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension)</s>. Tu `return` quedaría así:

```
#Buscamos en la tupla, del indice del número selecciónado y dos más hacia adelante
return sum([num for num in tupla[idx:idx+3]])
```

### Edición

El código anterior es una implementación innecesaria, es mejor usar la implementación de @abufalia en el comentario a esta respuesta.

Comment: la parte final puede simplificarse a `sum(tupla[idx:idx+3])`

Comment: Gracias @abufalia se me ha ido la cabeza y no sé en que pensaba, he editado la pregunta referenciando tú comentario!

Comment: Muchas Gracias Rubiales Alberto, por la explicación tan detallada y también Gracias abulafia por hacer-lo más sencillo, me ha quedado todo más claro y lo pondré en práctica!!